# How do I access a custom type once it is passed to another object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, openframeworks

I'm new to C++ so excuse me if my use of terminology is off.

I'm writing an app in openframeworks that makes use of a physics library called ofxMSAPhysics. For my purposes, I've created a custom class called "particle,"  which inherits from the MSAPhysics Particle3D class.

Here I pass a pointer to my custom object to the physics engine:

```
particle * p = new particle(ofVec3f(getTokenCoors(index)));
physics.addParticle(p);
```

In my custom class I have a public member called collide that I set to true when one particle collides with another. To do this, I override one of Particle3D's virtual methods:

```
void collidedWithParticle(ParticleT *other, ofVec3f collisionForce) {
        collide = true;
    }
```

Now I'd like to check to see when one particle collides with another. `physics.getParticle(i)` returns a particle from the physics engine, but one of the type `Particle3D`, and not of my custom particle type. So when I loop through the particles returned from `getParticle()`, none of them contain my "collide" variable.

Is there a way to access my custom particles once they are added to the engine?

Please let me know if I can clarify something.

EDIT: collidedWithParticle() is a virtual member of Particle3D. I just had my overridden method set collide to true to see if it worked.

Comment: What's the interface for `Particle3D`?

Comment: Is `collidedWithParticle` a virtual member function of `Particle3D`, or is it specific to `particle`?

Comment: @juanchopanza judging the way he phrased in his question, it would seem to be the former. But the way the method is named makes me think it should return a `bool` perhaps?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, the former. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if you're sure that all particles in the system are of your overiden type**, then you can simply cast the `Particle3D` to `particle` by using

```
particle* myParticle = static_cast<particle*>(other);
```

**but this way isn't of the safest ones**, i'd suggest you, if possible check maybe there are some methods that you could override in `Particle3D` class that would enable you to see if particle collided or save a list of your particles and use that list to be sure which particles are of your inherited type.
Of course `dynamic_cast` would be more appropriate and more safe, but i don't suggest using it because of RTTI, since RTTI heavily slows down code execution.

Comment: What you need is  a `dynamic_cast<particle*>(other)`.

Comment: Ah. I wondered if I could cast it, but I forgot the pointer identifier `(*)` in the `(particle*)`. Worked beautifully – thank you!

Comment: You really should not be using C-style cast here. Use `dynamic_cast` as suggested by juanchopanza for proper polymorphic behavior. If `other` isn't really a `particle*` then dynamic_cast will return `null`.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` requires RTTI, which heavily slows down code execution, that's why i suggest cstyle cast or static...

Comment: So you would rather use some code which can just do the wrong thing, just because it *might* be slower than the correct code?

Comment: @juanchopanza read about RTTI drawbacks, and as i mentioned in my answer cast isn't best option here in my eyes...

Comment: I don't need to read anything about RTTI, thanks. But you should read up on how badly the `static_cast` can go here.

Answer (score 0):

When you look through your particles, you need to have all the objects cast to the base class. You could technically have an array like so:

```
std::vector <Particle3D*> particles;
```

Because your own particle has inherited from this class, you can do the following:

```
particle* yourParticle = new particle();
particles.push_back(yourParticle);
```

You are allowed to do this because yourParticle is a class that has Particle3D as a base class. Thats just one of the many features of Object Oriented programming.